# Counting down and then up

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to run a function that will, given one variable, count down to zero and then up to the original variable. the output should look something like this:

```
>>> functionname(5)
5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

so far I've written the code below, but this doesn't count up all the way to the original variable. I guess I need to somehow save the variable in order to refer to it later, but I have no idea how to do that, since python automatically changes `n` as the function goes on.

```
def functionname(n):
    n = orginal
    while n > 0:
        print n
        n=n-1
    print n
    if n==0:
        print n
        n=n+1
```

I would be very grateful for some pointers, as I seem to be completely stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Just count from negative to positive and use math:

```
def fn(n):
    print ', '.join(str(abs(i)) for i in range(-n, n+1))
fn(5)
# 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Pointers:

- If you already know the range you want to iterate over, it's much cleaner and more direct to use a `for` loop instead of a `while`.
- You can use the `range` function to generate number sequences.
- You can convert simple `for` loops into list-comprehensions as I did above.

The "simple" clean implementation of your requirements would look something like this:

```
def fn(n):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        print i,
    for i in range(n + 1):
        print i,
```

Other notes:

- `range` can count backwards too
- The end argument to `range` isn't included in the range itself, that's why the second loop specifies `n + 1` as the limit (instead of just `n`)
- Adding a trailing comma on your `print` makes it add a space at the end instead of a line-break.

Answer (score 1):

Your second block is an `if n == 0:` (which you know it is since the `while` loop terminated when `n` hit 0); presumably you want `while n <= 5`.

Note that there are nicer ways to accomplish the same thing in Python. For example, using a pair of `range`s with `itertools.chain` to iterate each `range` one after another allows you to simplify to:

```
import itertools

def functionname(n):
    for i in itertools.chain(range(n, 0, -1), range(n+1)):
        print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd do something like...

```
def count(n):
    for x in range(n, -n, -1):
        print(str(abs(x)) + ",")
```

At the suggestion of dlewin, here's a list comprehension of the same...

```
def count(n):
    print(','.join(str(abs(x)) for x in range(n, -n, -1)))
```

Comment: Very elegant. I think this could worth a comprehension list

Comment: indeed : even better

Answer (score 0):

You need a second while loop that starts at 0 and goes back up to "original".
Do you know about "for" loops yet?  Those are better for counting.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea about having `original` is correct however you are using the assignment operator the wrong way 'round. Also the `if n==0` line should be another loop (`while` or `for` as suggested by other answers), counting back up to `original`.

So I'd start with copying the value from `n` to `original` like this:

```
original = n
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You got some bad formatting there. Remember to indent properly for functions and `while` and `if` statements.

So first, set `n` to 5. Then count down from there until you reach 0 with a `while` loop:

```
while n != -1:
    print n
    n -= 1
```

Then after the loop breaks, count back up again and reset `n` to 0:

```
n = 0
while n < 6:
    print n
    n += 1
```